# What is the efficient method to purge my Postgresql database of some huge amount of unnecessary data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to get rid of some unnecessary data from my Postgresql database.
Here is the query which works for small data:

```
WITH bad_row_history(survey_id, template_id) AS ((
SELECT row_id, (row_value->>'template_id')::INTEGER 
FROM public.row_history
WHERE record_table='survey_storage'
AND row_value->>'status'IN ('Never Surveyed','Incomplete Configuration')
AND row_id NOT IN (
        SELECT row_id
        FROM public.row_history
        WHERE record_table='survey_storage'
        AND row_value->>'status'='Ready to Launch'
        )
) LIMIT 10),
delete_su AS (
   DELETE FROM survey_user
   WHERE survey_id = ANY(ARRAY(select survey_id FROM bad_row_history))
),
delete_slu AS(
   DELETE FROM survey_library_users
   WHERE survey_library_id = ANY(ARRAY(select template_id FROM bad_row_history))
 ),
delete_ss AS(
   DELETE FROM survey_storage
   WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY(select survey_id FROM bad_row_history))
),
delete_sl AS(
  DELETE FROM survey_library
  WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY(select template_id FROM bad_row_history))
 )
delete FROM row_history
  WHERE row_id = ANY(ARRAY(select survey_id FROM bad_row_history))
```

In the cte, you will find I have added a limit.Otherwise the query never completes.Without limit the cte yields 937,147 rows.There are 5 delete statements.For each delete there could be at least one row and may be 3 to 5 rows at max.
I have 3 questions:

1. If the query could be improved? Instead of subquery should I use join?
   Instead of one script should I split into multiple scripts?
2. Second question is should I use pg_cron?
3. If I do not put the limit will it be able to handle?

I understand this will be a time taking job.Let it be, but at least it should work. Should not hang. Yesterday I ran it without LIMIT and after running few hours it hanged & all the deletions got rolled back.But earlier with small limits like 10, 100 it has worked.

**UPDATE** As per suggestions I have introduced temp table & deletes with sub-query to the temp table. Here is the script:

```
DROP bad_row_history if EXISTS;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bad_row_history (
survey_id int8 NOT NULL,
template_id int8 NOT NULL
);
ANALYZE bad_row_history;
INSERT INTO bad_row_history(survey_id, template_id)
(SELECT row_id, (row_value->>'template_id')::INTEGER 
FROM public.row_history
WHERE record_table='survey_storage'
AND row_value->>'status'IN ('Never Surveyed','Incomplete Configuration')
AND row_id NOT IN (
        SELECT row_id
        FROM public.row_history
        WHERE record_table='survey_storage'
        AND row_value->>'status'='Ready to Launch'
        ) 

);
DELETE FROM survey_user
WHERE survey_id IN (select survey_id FROM bad_row_history);
DELETE FROM survey_library_users
WHERE survey_library_id IN(select template_id FROM bad_row_history);
DELETE FROM survey_storage
WHERE id IN(select survey_id FROM bad_row_history);
DELETE FROM survey_library
WHERE id IN(select template_id FROM bad_row_history);
delete FROM row_history
WHERE row_id IN(select survey_id FROM bad_row_history)
```

**UPDATE-2**

disable_triggers.sql

```
    ALTER TABLE survey_user DISABLE TRIGGER ALL; 
    ALTER TABLE survey_storage DISABLE TRIGGER ALL; 
    ALTER TABLE survey_library DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

script

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE bad_survey (
    survey_id int8 NOT NULL,
    template_id int8 NOT NULL
);
analyze bad_survey;
insert into bad_survey(survey_id, template_id)
(select id as survey_id, template_id 
from survey_storage 
where status in ('Never Surveyed','Incomplete Configuration','Ready to Launch')
and id=original_row_id 
and tenant_id=owner_tenant_id
and tenant_id=5);
insert into bad_survey(survey_id, template_id)
(select pss.id, pss.template_id
 from survey_storage css
    inner join company_by_path cbp
        on css.company_by_path_id = cbp.id
        and css.tenant_id = cbp.tenant_id   
        and cbp.relationship_type = 'partner'
    inner join survey_storage pss
        on cbp.owner_tenant_id = pss.tenant_id
        and css.master_template_id = pss.master_template_id
        and css.tenant_id = pss.owner_tenant_id
        and css.source_id = pss.source_id
        and css.tenant_id != pss.tenant_id
        and css.template_id != pss.template_id
        and pss.id != pss.original_row_id
 where css.id in (select id as survey_id
                from survey_storage 
                where status in ('Never Surveyed','Incomplete Configuration','Ready to Launch')
                and id=original_row_id 
                and tenant_id=owner_tenant_id
                and tenant_id=5));
DELETE FROM survey_user su
    USING bad_survey bs
    WHERE su.survey_id = bs.survey_id;

DELETE FROM survey_library_users slu
    USING bad_survey bs
    WHERE slu.survey_library_id = bs.template_id;

DELETE FROM row_history rh
    USING bad_survey bs
    WHERE rh.row_id = bs.survey_id;

DELETE FROM survey_storage ss
    USING bad_survey bs
    WHERE ss.id = bs.survey_id;

DELETE FROM survey_library sl
    USING bad_survey bs
    WHERE sl.id = bs.template_id;
```

enable_triggers.sql

```
ALTER TABLE survey_user ENABLE TRIGGER ALL; 
ALTER TABLE survey_storage ENABLE TRIGGER ALL; 
ALTER TABLE survey_library ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that Postgres is materializing the CTE, i.e. computing ~1m rows and storing them in memory, then the delete queries convert that to an array 5 separate times, and that's very expensive and slow.

I *think* you could make it a lot faster by not converting to an array, i.e.

`survey_library_id IN (select template_id FROM bad_row_history)`

rather than

`survey_library_id = ANY(ARRAY(select template_id FROM bad_row_history))`

What I would probably do though is make bad_row_history a temporary table, with columns template_id, survey_id etc, and then run the deletes as separate statements with subselects on the temporary table. That way the optimiser should be able to work more effectively on each delete.

Comment: let me implement your suggestions one by one.First get rid of arrays.

Comment: I incorporated your suggestions, updated my question to show the code.Pl. may review.

Comment: we have not tested with staging/prod data.Already I found that I have not turned off the triggers which resulted in creating more data in row_history table which also needs to be cleaned. But now I have more confidence in script that it will be far more efficient than my 1st try. Once we have cleaned up staging environment I will inform you. Thanks.

Comment: So do I disable/enable triggers for individual tables or there is a way to set it globally for all 4 tables (barring the history table)?Thanks in adv.

Comment: it has been decided that we will not purge all the records at one go.But we will do it per tenant basis.I wanted to make the tenant_id as session variable as we do in MSSQL - do not know how to do that.I am updating the question so that I can show the code.

Comment: I also have to add messages which will print during execution of the script like "Done deleting bad survey user entries" etc.Tried to use "RAISE NOTICE 'Done deleting bad survey user entries' ".When I run it from DBeaver, it even fails to compile at raise notice.

Comment: I promised that I will get back to you to report if the changes led to any improvement in performance. The base table in prod had @400K unnecessary data.With associated records in other tables the number swells to 5x of this value.It has taken 4hrs 34 mins to delete this humongous data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing everything in a single statement, proceed like this:

- Create a temporary table from the result of the first CTE.
- `ANALYZE` that temporary table.
- Run one `DELETE` statement per table, joining with the temporary table.

Comment: I have incorporated your suggestion of adding analyze to the temp table.Still kept it as subquery, will change to join.

Comment: In the delete statements I forgot to disable/enable triggers which is supposed to pollute row history table.So do I disable/enable triggers for individual tables or there is a way to set it globally for all 4 tables (barring the history table).

Comment: If you are a superuser (or use a `SECURITY DEFINER` function, you can set `session_replication_role` to `replica`.

Comment: It has been decided that we will not delete all bad records at one go, but it will be on per tenant basis.I wanted to introduce a variable for tenant and if possible to get it from user.Do not know how to do it other than converting it to a stored procedure. Also I wanted to raise notice that deleted entries from this table for tenant id , could not do. I will need help.